# Three.js NURBS surface class name?

Tags: three.js

I'm looking at using NURBS surfaces with `THREE.js`,
and (what seems like older) documentation points
me to a `THREE.NURBSurface` class. Trouble is, I can't seem to find it in the official documentation, so I suspect it's been more recently changed.

So, my question is: under what name might I find such functionality, and where might I find a URL containing its documentation?

Answer (score 1):

The class has still the name `THREE.NURBSSurface`. When using `npm` you can import it like so:

```js
import { NURBSSurface } from 'three/examples/jsm/curves/NURBSSurface.js';
```

The class is undocumented so you don't find an entry in the official documentation. However, there is an official example that uses it: [webgl_geometry_nurbs](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_nurbs)

Comment: Thanks very much for that :-) ... trouble is, my;local,,recurrently-downloaded, copy of the `three.js` code-vbase ddoesn't contain `THREE.NURBSSurface`: so how will I be able to run my code?